# How to use links within a show/hide div

Tags: html, css

I have some css lines that allow me to hide/show a div. I would like to have links in this div, but when I test the link, it ends up hiding the div, it does not actually follow the link.
So, I want to be able to show the content, click the link. The content should remain open, and the link should be followed. Hope this makes sense!

```
<p>some text I want to show</p>
    <a href="#" class="hide">[...]</a>
    <a href="#" class="show">[...]</a>
    <div id="list">
      <p>bla bla, you should look on <a href="http://www.google.com">google</a></p>
    </div>
```

css

```
.show {
  display: none;
}

#list {
  display: none;
}

.hide:focus + .show {
  display: inline;
}

.hide:focus {
  display: none;
}

.hide:focus ~ #list {
  display: block;
}
```

I also made my first [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vanni82/3cn7yvds/).

As always, any help is appreciated!

Comment: change your `:focus` to `:active` - https://jsfiddle.net/3cn7yvds/2/

Comment: This seems to work just fine in IE11 and FF38 (on Windows). It looks like Chrome(Win) 49 is immediately removing focus, even if you hold the mouse down on it, or tab to it. The focus/blur is so fast that I usually don't see anything, but every now then I'll see a quick flash as everything repaints. Usually, adding a tab index fixes focus problems, but doesn't seem to help in this case. The fact it doesn't work even with the keyboard makes me think it's a Chrome bug, but I'm not sure how to work around it.

Comment: This is all quite easy to do with Javascript.  Is that an option?

Comment: @trex005 Javascript would be an option. thanks

Comment: @Elezar, I get the same bug on firefox (mac)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using Javascript/Jquery**

Jquery

```
jQuery(function($){
             $('#hideme').click(function(){
             $('#list').addClass('hidden')
           $('#list').removeClass('expand')
             })
        })

jQuery(function($){
             $('#showme').click(function(){
             $('#list').addClass('expand')
           $('#list').removeClass('hidden')
             })
        })
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/fido3993/w35qxL90/2/)

**Using Pure CSS**

HTML

```
<p>some text I want to show</p>
<div>
<a href="#" class="hide">[...]</a>
<a href="#" class="show">[...]</a>
<p id="list">bla bla, you should look on <a href="http://www.google.com">google</a></p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.hide:focus + .show + #list{
  display:none;
}

.show:focus + #list{
  display:block ;
}

#list{
  display:none;
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/fido3993/yjuujjhy/)

Comment: how would you make hide be the default?

Comment: @Stylize you also can use css but need to construct your html.

Comment: thanks! my only "complaint" is that when I click the link, the div reverts to hide again. is there a way to stop this? Thanks again

Comment: @ Fiido Firdauz The pure CSS version

Comment: @Stylize I'm sorry i can't find the solution for that. if me, wanna try to use click event, always use javascript rather using css.